# GLFW Fullscreen OS X in LWJGL 3

Tags: lwjgl, macos, glfw

How does one create a fullscreen window properly in OS X from the code, instead of just expanding into the current desktop?

I am referring to the sort of fullscreen window that one gets when the top-left-most green button is pressed.

*Is this actually possible?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, [This](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=4671.0) post caught my eye, where they said this property was added to the nightly build

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.enableOSXFullscreenModeAPI", "true");
```

Although you can always do it manually, see [Here](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/LWJGL_Basics_5_(Fullscreen)) for a whole tutorial on creating a full screen display.